# cakephp Get multiple values from parent table in one row

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have these tables

1 - Product Category
2 - Product 
3 - Product Model

and

4 - Quote Items

Now each row of quote item has these values

id, product_category, product_id, product_model_id, support_product_id, support_prouct_model_id

Now as you can see there are two instances of product and product model in Quote Item. I need product name and product model name to display on screen.

When I try to retrieve data in controller it only bring one value from product and product model while I need two instances of each product and product model.

Here's how I am trying to retrieve data.

```
$quote_items = $this->QuoteItem->find('all', array(
 'fields' => array(
                    'product_category_id',
                    'product_id',
                    'product_model_id',
                    'support_product_id, Product.name',
                    'support_product_model_id',
                    'quantity',
                    'length',
                    'unit_price',
                    'total_price',
                    'ProductCategory.name',
                    'ProductModel.name'

                ),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'quote_id' => $this->data['Quote']['quote_id']

                ),
                'contain' => array('Product', 'ProductModel', 'ProductCategory')
            ));
```

This is what I get in view. As you can notice it only get product name for first product and same for product model.

```
array (size=4)
      'QuoteItem' => 
        array (size=9)
          'product_category_id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'product_id' => string '30' (length=2)
          'product_model_id' => string '79' (length=2)
          'support_product_id' => string '28' (length=2)
          'support_product_model_id' => string '73' (length=2)
          'quantity' => string '33' (length=2)
          'length' => string '1' (length=1)
          'unit_price' => string '456' (length=3)
          'total_price' => string '15198' (length=5)
      'Product' => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'p3' (length=2)
          'id' => string '30' (length=2)
      'ProductCategory' => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'Iron' (length=4)
          'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'ProductModel' => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'm1' (length=2)
          'id' => string '79' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct form of the data you are getting. Probably in your model QuoteItem in your associations you have

```
belongsTo = array(
    'Product' => array(..), 
    'ProductCategory', array(...),
    'ProductModel' => array(...),
);
```

So add the following associations

```
belongsTo = array(
    'Product' => array(..), 
    'SupportProduct', array(
        'className' => 'SupportProduct',
        'foreignKey' => 'support_product_id',
     ),
    'ProductCategory', array(...),
    'ProductModel' => array(...),
    'SupportProductModel' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductModel',
        'foreignKey' => 'support_product_model_id',
     ),
);
```

So you can have multiple association to the same class with different association name.

Comment: No still same result nothing changed.

Comment: I am sorry i forgot to tell you that you have to updated the find query as well. With the new associations i told you does the `$this->QuoteItem->find('all')` brings also the associated `SupportProduct` and `SupportProductModel`;